# array of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

```
char *a[]={"diamonds","clubs","spades","hearts"};
char **p[]={a+3,a+2,a+1,a};
char ***ptr=p;
cout<<*ptr[2][2];
```

why does it display h and please explain how is the 2d array of ptr implementing and its elements

Comment: @tushar: If a question is homework, it is common practice in Stack Overflow to add a homework tag to it.

Comment: Wow. I think of myself as pretty darn good at C, and I _still_ find the above code very difficult to think through. If this is homework, I'm not sure how good of a homework problem it is. Seems to only test intimate knowledge of C's quirks. I can think of more useful things to teach...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that `x[y]` binds tighter than `*x`, so the expression `*ptr[2][2]` is interpreted as `*(ptr[2][2])`.

Also note that `x[y] == *(x+y)`.

Therefore

```
*(ptr[2][2]) == *(p[2][2])    // ptr = p
             == *((a+1)[2])   // p[2] == a+1
             == *(*(a+1+2))   // x[y] == *(x+y)
             == *(*(a+3))     // 1+2 == 3
             == *(a[3])       // *(x+y) == x[y]
             == *("hearts")   // a[3] == "hearts"
             == "hearts"[0]   // *x == *(x+0) == x[0]
             == 'h'
```

Comment: I sure wish we could see who just made that edit. I assume that only moderators can make edits without a trace like that. The edit is fine with me, but the anonymity seems uncool...

Comment: @sblom: No, it's just I removed that within 5 minutes.

Comment: This helped me to understand these types of declarations a little better: http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html.

Answer (score 5):

See KennyTM's excellent answer for an explanation... but I thought this would be the perfect case for professing the use of your debugger to "visualize" memory.. and provide an easy answer to this type of question.

[image]